# passing element reference through dynamically created html

Tags: javascript

Lets say that I have a element reference obtained ala...

```
var x=document.getElementById("ID123");
```

Now I want to include some function of x on a dynamically created html element ala...

```
myWin.document.write("<input  type='button'   data-doit=????? value='Do It'   onclick='window.doit(?????);'/>");
```

so that function doit() can recreate the original reference x

```
function doit()
{
var x = ?????;
}
```

Right now I'm doing this by obtaining a numeric index of x as found via getElementsByTagName and passing that as a parameter to doit().

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably pass the ID of `x` to `doit()`, which would require `doit()` to look something like this:

```
function doit(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    // etc
}
```

As far as creating the `input` element goes, there a couple of ways to do this. This is similar to your current solution (but non-standard):

```
myWin.document.write('<input ... onclick="doit(' + x.id + ');" />');
```

The standard solution is to create your new `input` element using the DOM API:

```
var input = myWin.document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
// other properties
input.onclick = function () {
    doit(x.id);
};
// insert new element
document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(input);
```

(Note that inserting the element is a little more complicated in this situation - you have to programmatically find its location in the DOM).

Finally, if you're using jQuery, you might do something this:

```
var input = $('<input type="button" etc />').click(function () {
    doit(x.id);
});
$('#myform').append(input);
```

Comment: Ok, that's a bit more elegant and simpler than I had been doing but I'll have to go back and add ids to the elements in question.  I do have a further question re ids.  I understand they should be unique.  But unique within what scope?  A particular window? document?  frameset?  If I create a window ala document.write, then come back later a recreate again using document.write, can the ids for the two pages overlap?

Comment: I don't quite get the line document.getElementById("myform").appendChild(input);
I see input is associated with myWin but shouldn't the document reference also be to myWin? I do want to put the button in a new page.  And this presupposes the existence of an element with ID "myform"?  Could that be the body tag?

Comment: Hi Mike. I was assuming you already had IDs assigned to the relevant elements from the snippet in your question (`var x=document.getElementById("ID123");`). As far as uniqueness goes, my understanding is that they must be unique within a document.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, yes, you're right, that line should also reference the same window/document that `input` was created in. "myform" was just an example ID - you could indeed append directly the `body` or any other element you can get a reference to.